# How to create a custom url on wordpress site to be called from an external server?

Tags: php, wordpress, api, url, callback

I am developing a plug-in for wordpress, and I need to expose an url to be called from a remote server that will send me 3 get variables.
my url(s) should be like this:

> http://www.example.com/api/videos/callback/?variable1=value1&variable2=value2&variable3=value3

where example.com is my website.

And when I receive the call I want to get this variables and something.

I have to receive 3 calls the first with 2 of this variables and seconde with 3 variables and the third one with 1 variable.
All of these calls will be the answer of my request sent with curl(but I think it doesn't matter).
I tried rewrite rules and add_endpoint but I didn't figure where and how to use it and if i need some additional plugin to do so.
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in case anyone want to know the answer, i simply used

```
      add_rewrite_rule('^api/videos/callback$', 'index.php', 'top');

      flush_rewrite_rules(true);
```

and for the variables i didn't make any thing, to access them i used $_GET and making all checks is exists i then execute my code.

Answer (score 0):

Use `wp_remote_get()` .

See the [Wordpress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_remote_get) for more info about this function.

Comment: thank you for your answer, i do not know witch url is calling me, so i need to prepare a url to be called and when is called and the variabeles are exist in query string i'll execute my code.

Answer (score 0):

You can install wordpress plugin json api for this
https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/
Also please go through installation notes 
https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/other_notes/

Comment: thank you for your answer,i don't think i need the json_api because after the call i'll do every thing by my side and i don't need to send any response to the remote server.

Comment: also i want to do every thing in my plugin (if it is possible) with no other plugins

Comment: To add Ajax to a plugin, please refer following document https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins